# selenium python delete text between xml tags

Tags: python, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to delete text between tags but is there better way than below

`<p>test_line</p>`

currently I am using action chains

```
action_chains = ActionChains(driver)
.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE).send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
```

So I'm doing above for 9 times. I see option `Keys.DELETE` but it's same thing

Comment: Have you tried `element.clear()` where `element` is your desired element?

Comment: yes clear doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from using `.clear()` which would only clear out the `value` attribute [by definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15172140/771848) and does not work for your use case, you can improve your current approach and build your action chains dynamically:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
for _ in range(9):
    actions = actions.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
actions.perform()
```

Or, even simpler:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE * 9).perform()
```

Note that this is still a *single selenium command* issued by `perform()`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried achieving that with the help of execute_script

so in js to remove text or inner html you can do following

e.g document.getElementsByTagName('p').innerHTML = '';

and to do above thing in selenium python you can try following

driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByTagName('p').innerHTML = '';")