# Why am I getting this error with selenium chromedriver?

Tags: node.js, selenium, express, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When the code below is executed it opens chrome and the search bar is filled already with this `data;,`. I haven't mentioned it anywhere in the code still this happens.
Moreover, there are few errors that appear each time I try to run the code.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

var driver =new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('wiki');
driver.findElement(By.name('btnG')).click();
driver.wait(check_title,1000);

function check_title(){
  var promise = driver.getTitle().then((title)=>{
    if(title === 'wiki - Google Search'){
      console.log('success!');
      return true;
    }else{
      console.log("failed!!");
    }
  });
  return promise;
}
```

I get this error

```
 (node:15384) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:61227
    (node:15384) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
    (node:15384) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:61227
    (node:15384) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4): Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:61227
    (node:15384) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 5): Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:61227
    (node:15384) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 6): Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:61227
```

How can this be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.clear();` to clear the input field for the search bar before you send keys to it. For details on what it does see the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167429/what-does-webelement-clear-do-to-textboxes).

The Promise is not handling the reject with a catch. Following the answers from another [question on promise rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500490/what-is-an-unhandled-promise-rejection).

```
var promise = driver.getTitle().then((title)=>{
    if(title === 'wiki - Google Search') {
      console.log('success!');
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log("failed!!");
    }
  }).catch(function () {
      console.log("Promise Rejected!");
  });
```